# Store the output of find command in an array

Tags: arrays, bash

How do I put the result of `find $1` into an array?

In for loop:

```
for /f "delims=/" %%G in ('find $1') do %%G | cut -d\/ -f6-
```

Comment: Could you be more clear? Not sure what you ment by `do %%G` and `for /f "delims=/" %%G`

Comment: It looks like you're mixing Bash/*NIX commands & syntax with Microsoft shell commands(`for /f`, `%%G`) & syntax. Correct your example to clarify the question.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

To loop through a find, you can simply use find:

```
for file in "`find "$1"`"; do
    echo "$file" | cut -d/ -f6-
done
```

It was what I got from your question.

Comment: This doesn't work if filenames contain spaces!

Comment: To work with filename containing spaces, simply quote the command like this: ```for file in "`find "$1"`"; do```

Comment: I just updated the code to fix this issue ;)

Comment: Still doesn't work that way. You just go through the loop once where "file" is assigned the string with all the files that `find` found. Plus the use of double quotes inside double quotes is fubar.

Answer (score 61):

I want to cry.

In bash:

```
 file_list=()
 while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
     file_list=("${file_list[@]}" "$file")
 done < <(find "$1" -print0)

 echo "${file_list[@]}"
```

`file_list` is now an array containing the results of `find "$1`

What's special about "field 6"? It's not clear what you were attempting to do with your `cut` command.

Do you want to cut each file after the 6th directory?

```
for file in "${file_list[@]}" ; do
    echo "$file" | cut -d/ -f6-
done
```

But why "field 6"? Can I presume that you actually want to return just the last element of the path?

```
for file in "${file_list[@]}" ; do
    echo "${file##*/}"
done
```

Or even

```
echo "${file_list[@]##*/}"
```

Which will give you the last path element for each path in the array. You could even do something with the result

```
for file in "${file_list[@]##*/}" ; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

#### Explanation of the bash program elements:

(One should probably use the builtin `readarray` instead)

```
find "$1" -print0
```

Find stuff and 'print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null character'. This is important as we will split that output by the null character later.

```
<(find "$1" -print0)
```

"Process Substitution" : The output of the `find` subprocess is read in via a FIFO (i.e. the output of the `find` subprocess behaves like a file here)

```
while ... 
done < <(find "$1" -print0)
```

The output of the `find` subprocess is read by the `while` command via `<`

```
IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file
```

This is the while condition:

```
read
```

Read one line of input (from the find command). Returnvalue of `read` is 0 unless EOF is encountered, at which point while exits.

```
-d $'\0'
```

...taking as delimiter the null character (see QUOTING in bash manpage). Which is done because we used the null character using `-print0` earlier.

```
-r
```

backslash is not considered an escape character as it may be part of the filename

```
file
```

Result (first word actually, which is unique here) is put into variable `file`

```
IFS=
```

The command is run with `IFS`, the special variable which contains the characters on which `read` splits input into words unset. Because we don't want to split.

And inside the loop:

```
file_list=("${file_list[@]}" "$file")
```

Inside the loop, the file_list array is just grown by `$file`, suitably quoted.

Comment: +1 This is the right way to do it; it handles spaces and other funny characters in filenames, which all the other posted answers fail on.

Comment: This certainly worked for me as a 'black box', but I was wondering if perhaps you (or anyone reading this) could point me in the direction of some tutorial that covers *how* it works (the combination of all the different parts, that is).

Comment: JonathanY.: You will want to read [Parameter Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html). and become familiar with [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).

Comment: Added explanation of program elements to @Sorpigal's answer.

Answer (score 13):

```
arrayname=( $(find $1) )
```

I don't understand your loop question? If you look how to work with that array then in bash you can loop through all array elements like this:

```
for element in $(seq 0 $((${#arrayname[@]} - 1)))
do
        echo "${arrayname[$element]}"
done
```

Comment: Error: "1.sh: 3: Syntax error: "(" unexpected"
this line: arrayname=( $(find /usr/dir1/dir2/dir3) )

Comment: @Gábor Varga: that error means you're using a basic shell that doesn't support arrays.  Use bash instead.  If this is a shell script, that means starting it with `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: @GáborVarga: This question is tagged `bash` so I presume you are using bash. If you are actually using POSIX sh or some other shell, please let us know.

Comment: Broken: fails with spaces and glob characters in file names.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not 100% foolproof, but it will probably work 99% of the time (I used the GNU utilities; the BSD utilities won't work without modifications; also, this was done using an ext4 filesystem):

```
declare -a BASH_ARRAY_VARIABLE=$(find <path> <other options> -print0 | sed -e 's/\x0$//' | awk -F'\0' 'BEGIN { printf "("; } { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { printf "%c"gensub(/"/, "\\\\\"", "g", $i)"%c ", 34, 34; } } END { printf ")"; }')
```

Then you would iterate over it like so:

```
for FIND_PATH in "${BASH_ARRAY_VARIABLE[@]}"; do echo "$FIND_PATH"; done
```

Make sure to enclose $FIND_PATH inside double-quotes when working with the path.

Comment: Broken: will not handle quotes, and is subject to code injection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler pipeless version, based on the version of user2618594

```
declare -a names=$(echo "("; find <path> <other options> -printf '"%p" '; echo ")")
for nm in "${names[@]}"
do
    echo "$nm"
done
```

Comment: Broken: will not handle quotes, and is subject to code injection.

Comment: somebody might use this for non internet related stuff, so code injection isn't a problem