# Command result to a variabe in for loop shell script

Tags: shell, variables, loops, for-loop

How to: a command result to a variable?

```
for file in find "$1" do
    var = $file | cut -d/ -f6-
    echo $var
    ...
done
```

Comment: A command result to a variable? variable=command (Where command is surrounded with `)

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers:

In shell scripts whitespace really matters. Your code `var = $file` is an error, since no executable `var` exists which knows how to process the arguments `=` and `$file`. Use

```
var="$file"
```

Instead.

To capture the output of your `$file | cut -d/ -f6-` pipeline you will need the following syntax:

```
var="$(echo $file | cut -d/ -f6-)"
```

In `bash` of recent version you can use a "here string" instead and avoid the expense of `echo` and the pipe.

```
var="$(cut -d/ -f6- <<<"$file")"
```

I note that you are also attempting to process the results of a `find` command, also with incorrect syntax. The correct syntax for this is

```
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file ; do
    var="$(cut -d/ -f6- <<<"$file")"
    echo "$var"
done < <(find "$1")
```

I must again question you as to what "field 6" is doing, since you've asked a similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213328/bash-script-find-output-to-array).

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't all that clear, but is

```
var=`cut -d/ -f6- < $file`
```

what you were after?