# Bash: Correct way to store result of command in array

Tags: bash

I want to find certain files, and loop over them, to print their names. What I have done is

```
DRAFT_FILES=(`find "$DRAFT_DIR" -name "*.md"`)
```

This gives me an array of all markdown files in the directory.

However, this is apparently not modern bash, according to [ShellCheck](http://shellcheck.net/) and [this guide](https://github.com/anordal/shellharden/blob/master/how_to_do_things_safely_in_bash.md), apparently the backtick is not good style. They recommend doing `"$( ... )"`, as far as I can tell. However, this

```
DRAFT_FILES="$(find $DRAFT_DIR -name '*.md')"
```

It only stores the first file found.

Can anyone help me?

I have looked at these answers before, but they seem to be outdated.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426529/reading-output-of-a-command-into-an-array-in-bash/32931403),
[2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439026/store-output-of-command-into-the-array).

Comment: Don't use the _accepted_ answer from the duplicated question - Use the other higher voted answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8214748/5291015

Comment: @Inian Thank you!